# SQL сортировка поиска по LIKE

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Необходимо результат запроса LIKE отсортировать в порядке нахождения по столбцам.

```
SELECT * FROM `events` WHERE `about` LIKE '%text%' OR `money` LIKE '%text%' OR `iked` LIKE '%text%'
```

Нужно, что бы первыми выдавались поля, найденные в **about**, потом в **money**, а в конце в **iked**.

На ум приходит множество способов, типа несколько запросов и сортировка массива с результатами выдачи непосредственно в PHP. Однако, можно ли сделать такое средствами SQL? Смотрел, например, оператор **ORDER BY**, но непонятно, как его применить для этой задачи.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM `events` WHERE `about` LIKE '%text%' OR `money` LIKE '%text%' OR `iked`   LIKE '%text%' ORDER BY about,money,iked
```

используйте DESC для обратной сортировки , если нужно , например about,money DESC,iked
но LIKE это само по себе тормоза...